# Outlook 2010 putting 1 pixel horizontal space between images in HTML email

Tags: html-email, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

I'm having a massive issue with something seemingly simple. I have a HTML email that I am creating. There is a section containing a row of images, some of them with links. Outlook keeps putting a single pixel horizontal space between the first image and the second. I had them in table cells, but even with the images simply in a row in the same table I still have the same issue.

The HTML source can be viewed here, where it looks fine in a browser - but copy and paste into outlook 2010 or 2007 results in the problem.

http://cogentec.co.uk/redbar/bar2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that although Outlook's compose view shows gaps between the images, once the email has been sent, it looks fine at the receiving end. Even if the recipient is the very same Outlook client that displayed the email incorrectly in compose view.

Solved.

Answer (score -1):

Your images all need `display:block;`. ALWAYS use this in email unless you are floating images (which is rare)